# WebGL rendering flashing extraneous squares instead of point cloud on safari

Tags: javascript, graphics, safari, webgl

I've been following a course on WebGL graphics and I've got to the point where we are trying to render a point cloud. I have successfully rendered several other objects and done a bunch with animating objects already. I'm a Mac user, and I mainly use safari so I've been running my test website with live-server on safari. When trying to implement the point cloud into my code the result on the website is a bunch of garbage. What was being rendered looked like a bunch of random sized, colored, and positioned rectangles flashing into the canvas.

I tried modifying my scale, transformations, rewrote my shaders in case I missed something, then finally I just ran it in chrome and it worked perfect. Switched back to safari and all hell broke loose again, the same issue. What I was expecting was a slowly rotating point cloud contained within the volume of a cube.
This is the code for the element on the website.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
const mat4 = glMatrix.mat4; 

if (!gl) {
    throw new Error('WebGL not supported');
}

function spherePointCloud(pointCount) {
    let points = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
        const r = () => Math.random() - 0.5; // -.5 < x < 0.5
        const outputPoint = [r(), r(), r()];
        

        points.push(...outputPoint);
        
    }

    return points;
}

const vertexData = spherePointCloud(1e5);

const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, `
precision mediump float;
attribute vec3 position;
varying vec3 vColor;
uniform mat4 matrix;
void main() {
    vColor = vec3(position.xy, 1);
    gl_Position = matrix * vec4(position, 1);
}
`);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, `
precision mediump float;
varying vec3 vColor;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1);
}
`);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));

const program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);

gl.linkProgram(program);

const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, `position`);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.useProgram(program);
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

const uniformLocations = {
    matrix: gl.getUniformLocation(program, `matrix`),
};

const modelMatrix = mat4.create();
const viewMatrix = mat4.create();
const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, 
    75 * Math.PI/180, // vertical field-of-view (angle, radians)
    canvas.width/canvas.height, // aspect W/H
    1e-4, // near cull distance
    1e4 // far cull distance
);

const mvMatrix = mat4.create();
const mvpMatrix = mat4.create();

mat4.translate(modelMatrix, modelMatrix, [0, 0, 0]);

mat4.translate(viewMatrix, viewMatrix, [0, 0.1, 2]);
mat4.invert(viewMatrix, viewMatrix);

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    mat4.rotateY(modelMatrix, modelMatrix, 0.03);

    mat4.multiply(mvMatrix, viewMatrix, modelMatrix);
    mat4.multiply(mvpMatrix, projectionMatrix, mvMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations.matrix, false, mvpMatrix);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertexData.length / 3);
}

animate();
```

This an image of what has been getting rendered on safari of this code

[image: This an image of what has been getting rendered on safari of this code]

This is an image of what is produced on chrome or what is supposed to be rendered on safari
[image: This is an image of what is produced on chrome or what is supposed to be rendered on safari]